# Slide In Animation as you scroll (same time)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I was searching for a very basic approach to make objects slide in from the side (images, divs etc.) as you scroll. So far I've only seen triggers which cause an animation at specific pixels and the objects slide in by themselves, but I want them to slide in the same time as you scroll and slide back as you scroll up again -> **Example**: http://nizoapp.com/ exactly like here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can see his entire function in this file: http://nizoapp.com/media/j/site.js

Comment: Thanks for the answre! Unfortunately I'm a noob in Jquery and and I can't really see what each of these functions do. If I just saw what function is needed to move ONE object I would understand

Answer (score 1):

This library may help: [Animate on scroll](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)